# String[] cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, compiler-errors, static-methods

So I'm writing a program where i ask the user to enter size of array and fill it with names. Later i ask user to type number and the program will search array for names that have length. However i keep getting a incompatible type error. String[] cannot be converted to string.

```
package LAB4_1;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LAB4_1

{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String names [];
    int length_typed;
    String names_printed; 

    // Read the number of kids
    System.out.print("How many kids are there? ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();

    // Read the names of the kids
    String [] kids = new String [size];

    for (int k = 0; k < kids.length; k++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter name of kid #" + k + ": ");
        kids[k] = sc.next();
    }
    // Print all the names of the kids and the length of their names
    System.out.println("Names of kids with lengths are: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < kids.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println(kids[i] + " " + kids[i].length());
    }

    // Prompt for sequence of name lengths:
      System.out.print("Enter lengths of names as promted, 0 to terminate.");

    // Read the lengths and print list of names till 0 is entered
      length_typed = sc.nextInt();
```

The error is here

```
      names_printed = LAB4_1.filterByLength(names, length_typed);
```

String[] cannot be converted to String. Am i not calling the method correctly?

```
      System.out.println(names_printed);

}

/**
 * Count the number of names in an array that have a certain length
 * @param names: An array of names
 * @param length : an integer length
 * @return the number of names in the array whose length is given
 */

static int countByLength(String [] names, int length)
{
int count = 0;

for(int i = 0;i < names.length;i++)
{
  if(names[i].length() == length) 
      count++;
}


return count;
}


/**
 * Filter an array of names and keep only those names with a given length
 * @param names: an array of names
 * @param length: an integer length
 * @return the array of names that have the given length
 */
static String [] filterByLength(String [] names, int length)
{
    String [] filtered = new String[countByLength(names, length)];
    int index = 0;

    for(int k = 0; k < filtered.length; k++)
    {
        if(names[k].length() == length) filtered[index++]=names[k];
    }

    return filtered; 
}
```

}

Comment: You are trying to assign a String array to a String variable.

Comment: I think the error message is completely clear, which you're assign `String[]` returned from `filterByLength` method to a `String` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not calling the method correctly. Your method `filterByLength` returns the type `String[]`. You are trying to place the value in a `String` object, namely `names_printed`.

That doesn't work. Retype your `names_printed` as a `String[]` and your code should work. However, you won't be able to use `println` and get a readable output. You should use `println(Arrays.toString(names_printed))`.